# Javascript/NodeJS: Invoking object methods inside the same object: why is "this." mandatory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, oop, scope

I'm a newbie with Node/Javascript (ES6). 
See example here below:

```
class MyClass {

    myTest() {
          console.log('it works')
        }

    runMyTest() {
          this.myTest()
        }

}
```

if I omit the `this.` in the `this.myTest()` line I get the runtime error:

> ```
>       myTest()
>       ^
> ```
>
> ReferenceError: myTest is not defined

It seems to me to be mandatory to invoke methods declared in the same object (a Class Object in this case)  of the caller, need the this.method()

That's correct?

In a similar way, I see that a parent method (of a subclassed object) requires super.parentMethod().

Coming from Ruby/other OO languages that sound weird to me.

Why the reason for mandatory `this.` / `super.` in JS?

---

**UPDATE:**

small workaround I found (to avoid this.method repetition):

```
class MyClass {

    myTest() {
          console.log('it works')
        }

    runMyTestManyTimes() {
          const mytest = this.mytest

          myTest()
          ...
          myTest()
          ...
          myTest()
          ...

        }

}
```

Comment: [Try this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fqupn1ec/2/)

Comment: The most direct answer would be because that's simply what the language specification requires. `this` is the calling context, whereas omission of `this` will only lookup the identifier from the scope, and call the function without a calling context if it's in scope, which in this case it's not.

Comment: I don't know Ruby (aside from basics for editing e.g. Vagrantfiles), but Java and Python both work this way. I thought Ruby used `@` for `this`. Does it really let you call methods with no referent?

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` refers to that instance of`MyClass` ( with the class methods on the prototype ) and without it, your method doesn't *see* the function because it's not looking in the correct place. It would use whatever is in it's scope i.e if the function `myTest()` was declared outside of the class globally.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was about to update it. It refers to that instance and has the prototypes of the class methods
Edit: updated, anyone correct me if I'm wrong, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because unlike Java or C# (which is most likely where you've seen this practice from), JavaScript can have functions that are not part of the class.

What will you do in this case?

```
class MyClass {
  myTest() {
    console.log('it works');
  }

  runMyTest() {
    myTest(); // oops
  }
}

function myTest() {
  console.error('It does not work! Oh my god everything is on fire!');
}
```